# How to implement OsmdroidMap Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, osmdroid

```
@Composable
fun OsmdroidMapView(geoPoint: GeoPoint) {
    AndroidView(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        factory = { context ->
            MapView(context).apply {
                setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.USGS_TOPO) // .MAPNIK doen't give me any proper view, just empty grey screen
                maxZoomLevel = 20.0
                minZoomLevel = 4.0
                isHorizontalMapRepetitionEnabled = false
                isVerticalMapRepetitionEnabled = false
                setScrollableAreaLimitLatitude(
                    MapView.getTileSystem().maxLatitude,
                    MapView.getTileSystem().minLatitude, 0
                )
                setScrollableAreaLimitLongitude(
                    MapView.getTileSystem().minLongitude,
                    MapView.getTileSystem().maxLongitude,
                    0
                )
                this.controller.setCenter(geoPoint)

                setBuiltInZoomControls(true)
                setMultiTouchControls(true)
                setUseDataConnection(true)
                tileProvider.clearTileCache()

            }
        },
        update = { view ->
        }
    )
}
```

It does not center. At the beginning I need to zoom it by myself to have proper view, not only small square.
See screens.
Where is the problem and why I cannot center my geoPoint?
After zooming the view is disaster it does not refresh.

[image: Initial view]

[image: Zoom view]

Comment: There's a `setZoom()` method to set the initial zoom level to something more convenient. Maybe in your code it would work like `this.controller.setZoom(12)` or something like that.